# UPDATE の使い方に関して: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, sql

PHP 初心者です！
今データを更新する練習してるのですが、このコードでデータを更新すると

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

というエラーが出ますが　色々調べたんですが　何が違うのかわかりません。
初歩的な質問ですみません。お願いします！

```
<?php include "db.php";?>
<?php include "function.php";?>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $query = "UPDATE users SET ";
    $query .= "username = '$username', ";
    $query .= "password = '$password' ";
    $query .= "WHERE id = $id ";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if(!$result) {
        die("query failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
    }
}

?>
```

function.phpのファイル

```
<?php include "db.php";

function showAllData() {

    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if(!$result){
        die('query connection failed' . mysqli_error());
    }

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        echo "<option value=''>$id</option>";
    } 

}
```

db.phpのファイル

```
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root','loginapp');

if(!$connection){
    die('Database connection failed');
}

?>
```

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query); の行の前に $query の値を表示させるか、ログに出力するようにして、内容を確認しましょう。　そうすれば、どこがSQLの構文に合っていないのかが判ると思いますよ。

Comment: SyntaxErrorは構文に起因するエラーなので記述が間違っているためコマンドが認識できないというエラーです。実際エラーをはいているのはPHPではなくSQLの方なので、Fumu7 さんの言うとおり、生成したクエリを一度確かめてみるといいです。あと質問に直接関係は無いのですが初心者とのことで、phpしか記述されないファイルの`?>`は記述しない方がいいですよ。 https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/ja/coding-standard.php-file-formatting.html

Comment: これって SQL インジェクション踏み踏み？

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます！助かりました。色々いじってみたところでいつの間にかで来てました！ありがとうございます！

Comment: @山田祐希 解決したようでよかったです。ですが、このままだと質問が未解決のまま残ってしまうので、もしよければ自己回答も出来ますので、自己回答後自分の回答を承認してください。

Comment: @774RR さんがご指摘の通り、このコードにはSQLインジェクションという重大な脆弱性があります。あくまで練習用に留め、製品には組み込まない・レビューを受けるようにお願いします。